# Gitflow and Version-Numbers in properties

Tags: maven, gradle, git-flow

We use gradle and have our Version-Number stored in gradle.properties.
Further we use "SNAPSHOTS" to identify builds from develop.

When creating a new release we remove the SNAPSHOT Postfix in develop, create a Release Branch and increase the Version-Number to the next SNAPSHOT Version in develop.

This process prevents merge conflicts for the gradle.properties, when finishing the release branch (which merges the last changes from release to develop branch).

But now we have the problem, that we have merge-conflicts (or worse fast-forward merges!) when creating hotfix-branches from master and merging them to open release branches and develop.

The same problem occurs with Maven Projects, where the Version-Number is located in the pom.xml.

Is there another good solution to prevent this problem? I was thinking about externalising the version-number and passing it e.g. via Build Parameter or store it in a file which is not under version control but this has the disadvantage, that you can't identify the version from the source.

Any help would be appreciate.

**UPDATE**

Another Idea is it, to use the Branch- / Tagname to identify the Release-Number.

Comment: Take a look here: http://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: That's what I meant with "externalizing the version-number and passing it via Build Parameter". It will work (also with Gradle) but I still have the problem, that I can't see the version-number within the repo (except I also version the command e.g. as shell script. But this will cause the same Gitflow-Problem).